# program not running due to problems in linking

Tags: segmentation-fault, undefined-symbol, nm

I am having troubles in executing the binary. the program is receiving segmentation fault.
The filtering is the out put of gdb

```
gdb a.out

(gdb) run
Starting program: a.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Then i used nm utility

```
nm -u a.out
      U Allocatememory
```

I found many symbols undefined. This a.out binary is actually got by linking many other .so. 
I did nm on one of the .so

```
nm libmylib.so
00000000000de6f  T Allocate memory
```

The program is linked with the above libmylib.so. I don't get any errors during linking.

```
g++ -m32  -shared -Wl -o a.out -lmylib
```

However, without -shared option, i am getting the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: <path_to_bin>/a.out: hidden symbol `__dso_handle' in 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/32/crtbegin.o is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
```

What could be the problem? Can some one suggest me how to over come this? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> g++ -m32  -shared -Wl -o a.out -lmylib

This builds a *shared library*, named `a.out`. Don't do that: shared libraries are not directly executable.

You'll want to do this instead:

```
g++ -m32 main.cc -o a.out -lmylib
```

where `main.cc` contains actual `main` function.

Comment: i am actually getting the following error

/usr/bin/ld: <path_to_bin/a.out>: hidden symbol `__dso_handle' in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/32/crtbegin.o is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @prabhu Please update your question with exact command you are using, instead of putting additional info into comments.